# Mostrar en formato JSON datos de una base de datos en SQL Server 2008 (AngularJS)

Tags: php, angularjs, sql-server, json

necesito de su ayuda en lo siguiente de favor:

Estoy utilizando AngularJS, tengo una base de datos en SQL SERVER 2008 son más de 5mil registros que tengo por tabla, lo que quiero hacer es traerme toda la información por medio de JSON y mostrarla, para poder hacer filtros de busqueda... ya tengo mi script, solo que me manda un error en la consulta donde me indica lo siguiente:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 47 bytes) in

Quiero pedir su consejo para saber si estoy realizando lo correcto o me recomiendan utilizar alguna otra tecnología como AJAX... les dejo el script que estoy utilizando por medio de AngularJS y PHP

```js
function conexion(){
 $srv="Servidor"; 
  $opc=array("Database"=>"BD", "UID"=>"USR", "PWD"=>"PASS");
  $con=sqlsrv_connect($srv,$opc) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  return $con;
}
```

```css
<?php
include ('conexion.php');
 $con = conexion();

 $sql="SELECT id_persona,nombre_completo,sexo, calle_no FROM PERSONAS ";
 $res=sqlsrv_query($con,$sql);

 $datos = array();

 while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
  $datos[] = $row;
 }

 echo json_encode($datos);

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="datosApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" css/style.css">

        <script>
        var misDatos = angular.module('datosApp', []);

        misDatos.controller("controladorDatos", function($scope, $http){

            $scope.importar = function(){
                //Se cambia succes por "THEN" y se le agrega .DATa al resultado
                $http.get('php/listas.php').then(function(datos){

                    $scope.equipo = datos.data;
                });
            }

            $scope.importar();
        });

//Agregar filtros
        misDatos.filter('cambiar', function(){
            var cambiarFiltro = function(valor){
                if (valor=='M') {
                    var nuevosDatos = "Masculino";
                }
                else{
                    var nuevosDatos = "Femenino";
                }
                return nuevosDatos;
            }
            return cambiarFiltro;
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input ng-model="buscarFruta" type="text">
        <div ng-controller="controladorDatos">

            <table>
                <caption>Usuarios</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Usuario</th>
                        <th>Contraseña</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tr ng-repeat="usuario in equipo | filter:buscarFruta">
                        <td>{{usuario.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{usuario.nombre_completo}}</td>
                        <td>{{usuario.sexo | cambiar}}</td>
                        <td>{{usuario.id_persona}}</td>
                        <td>{{usuario.calle_no}}<td>
                    </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias por su atención y espero haberme explicado!!

Comment: ¿Porqué traerte toda la información para luego filtrarla?, te recomiendo que en la consulta que estás haciendo a la BD le envíes los filtros necesarios. Asimismo, si tienes un montón de datos que mostrar tendrías que ver la alternativa de paginar la información a mostrar.

Comment: ¡¡Gracias por tu sugerencia!! trabajaré en eso..